# Is it possible to bootstrap Artifactory-OSS Docker image with Kubernetes Deployment and PVC?

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, artifactory, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volume-claims

We want to run bootstrap the default `artifactory.config.xml` and `security.import.xml` files to pre-define our users and repositories.

We'd also like to use persistent storage, specifically a PVC, to persist artifacts between container restarts.

[According to their documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker), you can setup extra config by placing config file into `artifactory_extra_config` and they will be copied into the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc` directory at container start. However, this does not seem to be the case for Artifactory OSS.

According to the [Helm chart](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/artifactory):

`Bootstrapping Artifactory
IMPORTANT: Bootstrapping Artifactory needs license. Pass license as shown in above section.`

[Documentation also mentions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuration+Files#ConfigurationFiles-BootstrappingtheGlobalConfiguration) that placing `artifactory.config.import.xml` and `security.import.xml` in the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc` directory allows for bootstrapping.

We have built a custom docker image from the Artifactory-oss:6.1.0 base image and simply copy two config files to the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc` directory, but attaching a PVC at `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory` seems to overwrite the config causing the bootstrap to fail.

I found that the Helm chart mounts a ConfigMap containing the bootstrap config files to a `/bootstrap/` volume and copies them to `/artifactory_extra_conf` in the `lifecycle.postStart` command. This does not appear to work either.

I've noticed that the `ENV` for [Artifactory PRO](https://bintray.com/jfrog/reg2/jfrog:artifactory-pro#) base image contains `ARTIFACTORY_EXTRA_CONF=/artifactory_extra_conf`while [Artifactory OSS](https://bintray.com/jfrog/reg2/jfrog:artifactory-oss) does not.

I've also attempted some experiments copy the config files in our custom image to other directories and copying loading the volume using `initContainers`, but so far nothing I've tried has allowed me to bootstrap Arrtifactory OSS AND use a persistent volume mounted at `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory`.

I noted in the Dockerfile for Artifactory that the `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory` sub directories are actually linked to the corresponding `/opt/jfrog/artifactory` directories in the base image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution was to modify their `/entrypoint-artifactory.sh` and create a custom image.

First, we added a new function `copyExtraConf()` to `/etnrypoint-artifactory.sh`

```
copyExtraConf () {
    logger "Copying from artifactory_extra_conf"
    chown ${ARTIFACTORY_USER_NAME}:${ARTIFACTORY_USER_NAME} /artifactory_extra_conf/*
    cp -pv /artifactory_extra_conf/* ${ARTIFACTORY_HOME}/etc/
}
```

Then we called it after we've setup directories and users to prevent ownership errors of a mounted volume:

```
printDockerFileLocation
checkULimits
checkMounts
setupDataDirs
setupArtUser

# CUSTOM:START - do this after setupDataDirs and setupArtUser so we can chown and copy our files.
copyExtraConf
# CUSTOM:END

setAccessCreds
setMasterKey
setupPermissions
setDBType
addExtraJavaArgs
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
#
# NOTE:
# entrypoint-artifactory.sh is based on the one from artifactory-oss:6.1.0
# When changing versions, be sure to compare entrypoint-artifactory-ta.sh to entrypoint-artifactory.sh
FROM docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:6.1.0

COPY entrypoint-artifactory.sh /entrypoint-artifactory.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint-artifactory.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint-artifactory.sh"]

COPY configs/artifactory.config.import.xml /artifactory_extra_conf/artifactory.config.import.xml
COPY configs/security.import.xml /artifactory_extra_conf/security.import.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to become root in order to exchange the /entrypoint-artifactory.sh

```
FROM docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:6.16.0
USER root
COPY entrypoint-artifactory.sh /entrypoint-artifactory.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint-artifactory.sh

COPY configs/artifactory.config.import.xml /artifactory_extra_conf/
COPY configs/security.import.xml /artifactory_extra_conf/

USER artifactory
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint-artifactory.sh"]
```